# How to propagate an configure option in an autotools project?

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

I have an autotools projet.
I can define a custom option to my top configure.ac (a "--enable-XX" option , using AC_ARG_ENABLE and AM_CONDTIONNAL). This is ok.

But now, i want to propagate this option to all my subdirectories.

How do i do ? :

Do i have to define the AC_ARG_ENABLE/AM_CONDTIONAL in every subdirectories configure.ac ?

//// Edit ////

Here is a schema of my working directory :

```
Project
  | configure.ac
  | Makefile.am
  | Component_1
      | configure.ac
      | Makefile.am (*)
      | src
          | Makefile.am
  | Component_2
      | configure.ac
      | Makefile.am (*)
      | src
          | Makefile.am

(*) SUBDIRS = src
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sub*directories* does not require creating sub*projects*.

In a typical Autotools project, only the top-level directory has a `configure.ac` or a `configure` script.  If there are makefiles or other artifacts to configure in subdirectories, then this is all handled by the one top-level script.  With such an arrangement, your question is moot -- there is nowhere to propagate the options *to*, and no reason to want to propagate them.

On the other hand, occasionally one project will incorporate a separate complete project.  If that incorporated project is an Autotools project then it will have its own `configure` script that should be run when the top-level project's is run.  This is arranged by use of the [`AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.70/autoconf.html#Subdirectories) macro in the top-level project's `configure.ac`.  The `configure` script in each designated subdirectory will be run with the same command-line arguments that the top-level `configure` was run with; you don't need to do anything else to forward the options.

It is a separate question, however, whether forwarding any particular option to a sub-project `configure` script makes sense.  The meanings, if any, of custom `configure` options are specific to each `configure` script.  If you have a subproject that you want to react in a specific way to a particular custom option, then it needs its own `AC_ARG_ENABLE` / `AC_ARG_WITH` and whatever else needs to go with it.  But if you feel at liberty to modify a subproject to add such things then maybe it ought not to be a subproject at all, but instead fully integrated, so that it is configured directly by the top-level script.

Comment: Thanks. The autotools project i have designed is like your second description but I use AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile subdir1/Makefile subdir2/Makefile]) in my top configure.ac and i have a configure.ac in each subdir => tedious so.
This was the template i received.
I don't know how to do only one configure.ac with subdirs.

It is possible to give me a link or an soft example ?

Maybe use "AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([subdir-objects])"?

Comment: @YopAndMail, if the top-level `configure` script configures all the makefiles throughout the whole project tree, then what do you need the others to do?  Do they run at all?

Comment: Because it sounds like you're *already* effectively following the one-`configure` route, notwithstanding the presence of multiple `configure.ac` files.  Remember that `configure`'s essential job is to build files from templates -- `Makefile`s especially, but other files too, sometimes.  If you already have one `configure` script doing that work for the whole tree then what more do you think there is to do to get to single-project alternative?

Comment: Automake's `subdir-objects` option is relevant only if your project is structured to use non-recursive `make`.  That's largely a separate consideration.

Comment: Sorry for the (Christmas) break. I have edited my post where i add a schema of my autotools architecture. So are there too much configure.ac ?

Comment: @YopAndMail, the question, again, is what purpose the per-component `configure.ac` files are intended to serve, given that the one at the root sets up all the makefiles throughout the tree.  If the subdirectory `configure.ac` files don't, in practice, configure anything then yes, they are extraneous.

Comment: Or to look at it another way, `configure.ac` and the scripts and artifacts that Autoconf builds from it are *per-project* assets.  If your various components are developed and released together as a unified project then it does not make sense to have multiple `configure.ac` files.

Comment: iI make sense to me to use it as you said because it is too tedious to maintan and it does appear in all tools i have installed using autotools. So, if i understand, i need to change my top `configure.ac` to output all the under-makefiles for each component using `AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile Component_1/Makefile Component_1/src/Makefile Component_2/src/Makefile])`. I think `Component_1/Makefile` is useless. Is it the right way to do it ? Thanks for all.

Comment: @YopAndMail, yes, it is conventional to set up a single top-level `configure.ac` as you describe.  It should construct all the makefiles your project needs.  That does not necessarily mean a makefile in every subdirectory, but what it *does* mean is specific to your project.

Comment: ok, as soon as i can, i will work on it. I put it as solved despite it all i still haven't do it. The explanations were clear.